# How to assert text of the input in selenium webrdriver - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, assertion

I'm starting to learn automated testing and I don't know how to assert input text i selenium webrdiver in python. Could You help me?

This is my code - but it doesn't work properly

```
def assert_element_text(self, driver, xpath, expected_text):
        element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
        element_text = element.text
        assert expected_text == element_text
   
 def assert_surname(self):
        self.assert_element_text(self.driver, self.surname_field_xpath, self.expected_surname)
```

I have assertion error

I also use robot framework and 'Textfield Value Should Be' works in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get value of input element, by:

```
element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
element_text = element.get_attribute("value")
assert expected_text == element_text
```